# Express.js: how to make express.static have higher priority than the rest of the app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express.js app set up like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
...
app.all('*', require('./routes/all'));
```

So when I try to load `/stylesheets/style.css`, request is dispatched to the `routes`. How do I make the app first try to use "static", and then - the catch-all route?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Middleware get executed in sequential order. Simply put the static middleware before the routing middleware.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Comment: @DeaDEnd how high would you push `express.static()` in the middleware stack? Before: session(), cookieParser(), methodOverride(), bodyParser(), logger(), errorHandler() etc?

Comment: Think about what middleware are required by which. `express.static()` does not need any one of those. Only put `logger()` in front of it if you want to log requests to static files.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't the default when you run express(1) to generate an app.

Comment: Be aware that app.configure is completely removed from version 4.0! github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/936 (cit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637148/using-app-configure-in-express#comment-35857511)