# Using app.configure in express

Tags: node.js, express

I found some code where they set up Express without using `app.configure` and I was wondering, what's the difference between using `app.configure` without an environment specifier and not using it?

In other words, what's the difference between this:

```
var app = require(express);

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.port);
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));  /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'site')));
}
```

and this:

```
var app = require(express);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.port);
app.use(express.logger('dev'));  /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'site')));
```

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK nothing. `app.configure` had to be used in older express versions but not now.

Comment: thanks, this question alone helped me solve my problem. How nice is that? :)

Comment: inside `require` the `express` should be in `quotes' `.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It is optional and remain for legacy reason, according to the doc.
In your example, the two piece of codes have no difference at all.
http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure

**Update 2015:**

@IlanFrumer points out that app.configure is removed in Express 4.x. If you followed some outdated tutorials and wondering why it didn't work, You should remove `app.configure(function(){ ... }`. Like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(...);
app.use(...);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Be aware that `app.configure` is completely removed from version 4.0! https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/936

Comment: Any time you use a version of Express that you haven't used before it's a good idea to check for a doc on migrating to new version https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x