# Express.js "app.use() requires middleware function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sass

I'm learning Express.js 4 and Node, and I'm getting an error that I haven't been able to figure out.

I'm trying to use the node-sass package to compile my sass code, but I haven't been able to get it up and running.

Here is a stripped down version of my main file:

```
var express = require('express');
var sass = require('node-sass');

var app = express();

app.use(sass.middleware({
    src: __dirname + "/assets",
    dest: __dirname + "/static",
    debug: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    res.send("Hello World");    
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Node is now listening.");
});
```

When I run this with `node server.js`, I get an error thrown back at me:

```
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
```

From this, I'm assuming that `sass.middleware` is not a middleware function...

1. What does this error mean?
2. Why is it being thrown?
3. How do I fix it?

---

The closest answer I've been able to find was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242536/how-to-install-sass-with-express) question, but from what I gleaned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202232/express-has-no-method-configure-error) is that these answers will only work with Express 3.

I would much appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction for how to setup Express 4 and Sass together (if indeed this is possible).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `node-sass` readme mentions that the [middleware has been moved](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#connectexpress-middleware) to [`node-sass-middleware`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware). So if you `npm install node-sass-middleware` and then do:

```
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: __dirname + "/assets",
  dest: __dirname + "/static",
  debug: true
}));
```

it should work.