# About nodejs program error

Tags: node.js

```
var express = require("express") ,http =require("http");
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
});

app.get("/", function(request,response){
    var message = ["<h1>Hello guys</h1>"].join("\n");

    response.send(message);
});

app.get("/user/:userId", function(request,response){
    response.send("<h1>Hello, user # " + response.params.userId + ".");
});
```

Error:-

app.configure(function(){});
TypeError: app.configure is not a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using app.configure in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637148/using-app-configure-in-express)

Comment: Okey. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

app.configure has been dropped from Express 4, see: https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x.

Instead you can do the configuration directly:

```
 app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

 app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Comment: Okay. Let me try.